# Custom hook - setting value based on API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Overview**

I have written a hook which executes an XHR request via a function and sets state based on the return value of that XHR Request. I would like to share the function that executes the XHR request as well as the state value and setter.

**Code**

```
export function useOpenItems() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    get_open_items();
  }, [count]);

  function get_open_items() {
    const response = get_data('/my/api/endpoint`);
    response.then(
      function(res) {
        setCount(res.data.length);
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  return [count, setCount, get_open_items];
}
```

FYI - In case you are curious, my 'get_data' function is just an AXIOS wrapper like:

```
export async function get_data(endpoint) {
    return await axios.get(endpoint);     
}
```

Is this the correct way to use a hook? I want to be able to call my get_open_items() function to update a count that is eventually rendered by a few different components.

EDIT: Adding component that references updated count:

```
export function ListItems() {
  const [count, setCount] = useOpenItems();

  return (
    <List>

      <ListItem button component={Link} to="/requests">
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Badge badgeContent={count} color="secondary">
            <Requests />
          </Badge>
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Requests" />
      </ListItem>

    </List>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems legit. The only thing maybe needs some cleanup

```
xport function useOpenItems() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    get_open_items();
  }, [count]);

  async function get_open_items() {
    const response = await get_data('/my/api/endpoint`); // You are already using async/await in get_data, so you can there
    setCount(response.data.length);
  }

  return [count, setCount, get_open_items];
}
```

Comment: I have updated my original post with component that uses the hook. Looks like maybe I need a useEffect function to get the count to update? Thank you for your feedback